# What is the correct typescript type for react children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, children, react-props

I'm trying to properly type the props for a component that maps children:

```
type Props = {
    children: any
}

const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = () => (React.Children.map(children, someMapingFunction);
```

I've been using `JSX.Element` but that doesn't quite feel right.

Comment: I use `React.ReactNode`

Comment: Are you trying to type your children to a specific controlled type? If not, you should probably use `React.PropsWithChildren<MyProps>`. That adds the default children to any props.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looking through the code under [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/26fb8aa1a6f1ac6eda00b752dddff6e79eb2e825/types/react/index.d.ts#L195) it appears that `children` is typed as `ReactNode`.

Example:

```js
type Props = {
    children: ReactNode
}

const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = () => (React.Children.map(children, someMapingFunction);
```

*Note*: The `ReactNode` type can be found in the React namespace:

```
import React from 'react';

let someNode: React.ReactNode;
```

Comment: And if the component takes children optionally, then `children?: React.ReactNode` is the right type.

Answer (score 1):

The `children` is a prop like any other and can be of any type. It's only special insofar that child JSX elements are automatically mapped to the `children` prop.

So, while it's usually declared as `children?: React.ReactNode`, you could declare it as a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), or even as a custom type like so:

```
interface INameProps {
    children: {
        fistName: string,
        lastName: string
    }
}

const Name: React.FC<INameProps> = ({children}) => {
    return <div>{children.fistName} {children.lastName}</div>;
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
<Name>
    {
        {
            fistName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith"
        }
    }
</Name>
```

Which is the same as:

```
<Name
    children={
        {
            fistName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith"
        }
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to specify `children` if you're using `React.FunctionComponent`.

For example the following codes compile without error:

```
const MyComponent: React.FC<{}> = props => {
  return props.children
}
```

Comment: I know that you don't need to. For completeness I like to specify children on the props for components that take children.

Comment: This is no longer the case with React 18 - `children` were [removed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210) from `Raact.FC` (which is now the same as `React.VFC`) and so you need to declare them explicitly.

Comment: So with React 18, how should they be typed for a wrapper of render with a redux store?

Answer (score 0):

It's not `ReactNode` but `ReactElement<any, any> | null`.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e90f1299270f6d602fa1af074fb5b3b088c53c09/types/react/index.d.ts#L511

```
    interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
        displayName?: string | undefined;
    }
```

Comment: using any turns off typechecking, thus usually no good practice..

Comment: You can send a PR to react types to consider changing that. But currently this is the exact type react uses, see the link.

Comment: that doesn't look like type of `children` prop, it's the type a `FunctionComponent` is expected to return?  Type of `props.children` depends on `P` type parameter, but is not constrained here by default.