# React 18 TypeScript children FC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I upgraded to React 18 and things compiled fine. Today it seems every single component that uses children is throwing an error. `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IPageProps'.`

Before children props were automatically included in the `FC` interface. Now it seems I have to manually add `children: ReactNode`. [What is the correct typescript type for react children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61236537/what-is-the-correct-typescript-type-for-react-children)

Is this part of the React 18 update, or is something screwed up in my env?

package.json

```
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"next": "12.1.4",
"@types/react": "18.0.0",
"@types/react-dom": "18.0.0",
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Looks like, for whatever reason, they took out `children` on the Component class

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800185/458193) is correct, I want to note that you absolutely don't *have to* use this `PropsWithChildren` helper. (It is primarily useful for the [codemod](https://github.com/eps1lon/types-react-codemod#implicit-children), not manual usage.)

Instead, I find it easier to define them manually.

### Before

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {};
const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {...}
```

### After

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode
};
const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {...}
```

That is all that's needed.

Or you can stop using `React.FC` altogether.

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode
};

function Component({children}: Props): React.ReactNode {
  ...
}
```

In React, `children` is a regular prop and is not something special. So you need to define it just like you define all the other props. The previous typings that hid it were wrong.

Comment: I know this is a bit off-topic, but do you think `ref` will ever be a "regular prop" too? Typing `ref`, especially for components wrapping other components, is usually very difficult. `React.ComponentProps` would solve it if `ref` were a normal prop.

Comment: At some point, I think so — there are some changes we need to make before we can do that. I don't see why typing it would be complicated though. That's probably a separate discussion and you're welcome to start it in the DefinitelyTyped repo.

Comment: That's good to hear. The issue is related to typing `forwardRef` for a design system library. For `const Box = styled(View)`, I'm not sure how to make `Box` have the same ref type as `View`, whereas for the props this is easy with a generic. I'll continue this on the DefinitelyTyped repo though, thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: Thanks for the help/answer. Where would one make this change in the code to work as it used to <v18? Asking specifically to keep compatibility with types coming from third-party dependencies.

Comment: What about `VFC`? It all seemed pretty straightforward: `FC` added implicit `children`, `VFC` did not. Now in React 18 it seems both are the same because...? It looks like I'll be creating a new `type CFC<T> = FC<PropsWithChildren<T>>` to restore that distinction.

Comment: @DanAbramov: can we get a `React.FCC<Props = {}> = React.FC<PropsWithChildren<Props>>` so that we are on-parr with the old interface?  This is not an uncommon use case to just have `React.FCC`.

Comment: @DanAbramov Using React.ReactNode as return type doesn't seem like a good recommendation since rendering such a component from the top of another component results in: [tsserver 2786] [E] 'Example' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'. Try this: 
function Example (): React.ReactNode { return <div /> }; 
function Other(): React.ReactNode { return <Example /> }

Comment: Omitting return type entirely might be better. tsserver will automatically warn about invalid return as long as there is code that tries to use the component.    function Example () {};    <Example />   You could put a usage in the same file like this, then tsserver will warn if invalid. You could even skip assigning to a variable.

Comment: @dalmo React.VFC is deprecated in React 18: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59882

Comment: This breaking change is really terrible. A lot of teams explicitly used FC to imply "adds a children prop", and used VFC to imply "doesn't add a children prop", and while the above fixes can work, in theory, in reality, it's much much more complicated, as a lot of _libraries_ made the same assumption. Please please please consider reverting this change.

Comment: you probably don't want to use ʼimport * as React ʼ (for reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/55287189/1701178)

Answer (score 83):

## How to resolve

### No props

#### Before

```
import React from 'react';

const Component: React.FC = ({children}) => {...}
```

#### After

*Create e.g. react.d.ts to define your helper type* <sup>1</sup>

```
import React from 'react';

export type ReactFCWithChildren = React.FC<PropsWithChildren>;
```

```
import {ReactFCWithChildren } from './react';

const Component: ReactFCWithChildren = ({children}) => {...}
```

or

```
import React from 'react';

const Component: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren> = ({children}) => {...}
```

### With props

#### Before

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  ...
}
const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {...}
```

#### After

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  ...
}
const Component: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<Props>> = ({children}) => {...}
```

or

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props extends React.PropsWithChildren {
  ...
}

const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({children}) => {...}
```

---

<sup>1 <sub>*While [defining `children` manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809927/519333) seems easy, it's better to leverage types that are already prepared for you in @types package. When there are changes to the type in the future, it will automatically propagate from the lib everywhere in your code so you won't have to touch it yourself.*</sub></sup>

### Suppress warnings for some reason

You can override react types by creating `react.d.ts` file with following definition which would revert the type to @types/react v17

```
import * as React from '@types/react';

declare module 'react' {
  interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
  }
}
```

---

### Why did FC signature change

`children` prop was removed from `React.FunctionComponent` (`React.FC`) so you have to declare it explicitly.

TS will tell you errors like

> Type '{ children: ...; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'."

[You can read why here](https://solverfox.dev/writing/no-implicit-children/). TLDR it prevents bugs like

```
const ComponentWithNoChildren: React.FC = () => <>Hello</>;

...

<ComponentWithNoChildren>
   // passing children is wrong since component does not accept any
   <UnusedChildrenSinceComponentHasNoChildren /> 
</ComponentWithNoChildren>
```

Comment: The first option has ts error `Generic type 'PropsWithChildren' requires 1 type argument(s).`, but the second one is just perfect

Comment: @LaszloSarvold I've reflected your comment, thx.

Comment: This is great, what about third party libraries? I've been hacking it `const ThirdPartyHack: any = ThirdParty`

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry unfortunately, you'll have to wait for libraries to adapt this (my answer ideally :D)

Comment: Note you don't have to use this PropsWithChildren helper. You can just define children manually, like any other prop. I'd say this is a clearer and simpler approach because it doesn't introduce new concepts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809927/458193

Comment: This is breaking the React "promise" of backward compatibility from one version to the next, at least in regards with TypeScript typings. Indeed, one can't update to the new typings if only one of their dependency is still on React 17. 

So if you have dependencies, you can only:
- Update them all only when they are all using React 18 typings
- Or not updating ANYTHING at all, because you can't just update one dependency that's on React 18 while the rest is on React 17 (again, only talking about typings).

Comment: @AntoineJaussoin Strictly saying, there is no "promise of backwards compatibility" between major versions — major versions _are_ for making backwards-incompatible changes. While we've tried to make React 18 as easy to adopt as possible, if you decided to adopt TypeScript, sometimes you're going to have to deal with bugfixes in typings, and those may take time to propagate through the ecosystem.

Comment: @DanAbramov: fair, I was referring to the "Gradual Upgrades via Warnings" concept, where you only get warnings (at worst) when upgrading from one version to the next. I understand it doesn't apply to TypeScript though, but I am at least saying that this is going to impact a lot of people and it would have been beneficial to apply this "Gradual Upgrades via Warnings" policy to the typings as well.

Comment: Unfortunately we’re pretty limited in what kind of warnings we can emit in TypeScript. We could _deprecate_ the children prop but of course that would be a lot more confusing. (The only problem was its wrong type.)

Comment: `extends PropsWithChildren<unknown>` is the best answer>

Comment: Since June 2022 it is no longer necessary to write `PropsWithChildren<unknown>` because [PR #60641][1] was merged that makes `unknown` the default value of the generic parameter to `PropsWithChildren`.


  [1]: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/60641

Comment: The "Suppress warnings for some reason" doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why. I just get a different error -- `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'MyProps | PropsWithChildren<MyProps>'`

Comment: It does not exist on `MyProps`. Use only `PropsWithChildren<MyProps>`

Comment: I am only using `PropsWithChildren<MyProps>`, using the override listed above. I'm saying it still persists with this TypeScript error. The TS ambient declaration doesn't appear to have the desired effect.

Comment: @MatthewDean Were you able to get it working using "Suppress warnings for some reason" way. I am trying same way but getting similar Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IProps | PropsWithChildren<IProps>'. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75695828/property-children-does-not-exist-on-type

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the React.FC type has changed. But you can declare your own type with blackjack and react children.

My way is to create `src/types/react.d.ts` with content like this:

```js
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

export type ReactFCC<T> = React.FC<PropsWithChildren<T>>;
```

### Update #01

You can add default value for the `T` parameter:

```js
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

export type ReactFCC<T = Record<string, unknown>> = React.FC<PropsWithChildren<T>>;
```

or

```js
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

export type ReactFCC<T = unknown> = React.FC<PropsWithChildren<T>>;
```

You can now choose not to specify a type in a `ReactFCC` generic without warnings.

Before:

```js
export const Component: ReactFCC<SomeType> = props => {

  const { children } = props;
  
  /* ... */
}
```

After:

```js
export const Component: ReactFCC = props => {

  const { children } = props;
  
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## Create your custom functional component type (a modification of `FC`).

#### Lets name it `FCC` (Denoting:- Functional component with children ;)  )

```
// Put this in your global types.ts

import { FC, PropsWithChildren } from "react";

// Custom Type for a React functional component with props AND CHILDREN
export type FCC<P={}> = FC<PropsWithChildren<P>>
```

#### Whenever you want `children` property in you Component's `props`, use it like this:

```
// import FCC from types.ts
const MyComponent: FCC = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <>{children}</>
  )
}
```

**OR**

```
interface MyCompoProps{
  prop1: string
}

const MyComponent: FCC<MyCompoProps> = ({children, prop1}) => {
  return (
    <>{children}</>
  )
}
```

> **PS** This answer might look similar to @Garvae's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72087687/12872199) but his `ReactFCC<P>` `type` should be written like `ReactFCC<P={}>` to prevent this following error:
>
> > `Generic type 'ReactFCC' requires 1 type argument(s)`
>
> This error occurs when you are passing no props to the Component. children prop should be an optional prop.
> So giving those props a default `{}` value (i.e `P = {}`) solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As Dan points out in his answer, you may not need `React.FC` any more. Here's an additional suggestion for if you choose to use a plain `function`.

### Component without children

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
};

export function Component({}: Props) {
  ...
}

<Component /> // Valid
<Component>test</Component> // Invalid
```

### Component with children required

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode
};

export function Component({children}: Props) {
  ...
}

<Component>test</Component> // Valid
<Component /> // Invalid
```

### Component with children optional

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode
};

export function Component({children}: Props) {
  ...
}

<Component>test</Component> // Valid
<Component /> // Valid
```

Using React.ReactNode as return type doesn't seem like a good recommendation since rendering such a component from the top of another component results in: [tsserver 2786] [E] 'Example' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'. Try this: function Example (): React.ReactNode { return  }; function Other(): React.ReactNode { return  }

Omitting return type entirely might be better. tsserver will automatically warn about invalid return as long as there is code that tries to use the component. function Example () {};  You could put a usage in the same file like this, then tsserver will warn if invalid. You could even skip assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

[It looks like the `children` attribute on the typescript typings were removed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/55dc209ceb6dbcd59c4c68cc8dfb77faadd9de12#diff-32cfd8cb197872bcba371f5018185d2e75fa540b52cda2dd7d8ac12dcc021299L500).

I had to manually add children to my props; There is probably a better solution to fix this, but in the interim, this works.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare FC17/VFC17 types that are backwards compatiable.

Add the following file to your project.

**types.d.ts**

```js
import {FunctionComponent, PropsWithChildren} from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
    type FC17<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<P>>;
    type VFC17<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
}
```

You can now search/replace all occurrences of FC and VFC in your source code to use the new types. Make sure to use case and exact word matching.

Your component code should end up like this:

```js
import {FC17} from 'react';

export const MyComponent: FC17 = ({children}) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

You can now continue to work, and progressively modify your code to use the new React 18 types anyway you want.

Answer (score 1):

first, you have to define a global interface

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

interface ReactFC<T = {}> extends React.FC<PropsWithChildren<T>> {}
```

component's props

```
    interface ReceiptProps {
       onSubmitForm: () => void;
       orderId: number;
    } 

    const Receipt: ReactFC<ReceiptProps> = ({orderId, onSubmitForm,children }) => {
        return <div> { children } </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better to avoid the 'FunctionComponent'/'FC' and do the following. this avoids one extra burden of being complied to the 'FunctionComponent' type declaration

```
import React, {ReactNode} from 'react';

interface Props {
    children: ReactNode;
}

function Component({children}: Props):JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div>{children}</div>
    );
}

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
```