# React.FC need to explcitly declare children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this simple component

```
export interface TagProps {
  onClick: () => void
  // children: React.ReactNode
}

const TagComponent: React.FC<TagProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return <Wrap>{children}</Wrap>
}
```

I got `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'TagProps'`

unless I remove the comment at `// children: React.ReactNode`. As I remember I don't have to give children a type if I use `React.FC`.

Comment: You need to explicitly declare any props you want to use in your components.

Comment: That's how it used to be, with react18 it's changed: [React 18 TypeScript children FC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809927)