# How to type Functional Components in React with "@types/react": "^18.0.17"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

React.FC type doesn't contain children prop anymore. How should I type my components now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71788254/11399221 hope this helps you.

Comment: thank you, my bad I didn't google enough, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question, but you can add children as prop like usual and define an interface for the props:

```
interface YourComponentProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}
export const YourComponent = (props: YourComponentProps) => {
  return <></>
}
```