# Did React.FC stop using PropsWithChildren

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my *memory*, you could write this:

```
const SomeComponent:FC<{label: string}> = ({label, children}) => (
```

and I even found [some documentation](https://www.carlrippon.com/react-children-with-typescript/) claiming you can do it.  When I try (with React version 18.2), I just get an error saying `children` is not a prop.

When I do this

```
const SomeComponent:FC<PropsWithChildren<{label: string}>> = ({label, children}) => (
```

it works fine, but that’s wordy.  Did this used to work and they changed it and nobody told me?  Why did they change it?  And why did nobody tell me?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809927/9201587) out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they changed it! Implicit `children` prop removed from  `React.FunctionComponent` types. in React version 18. you can check it [here](https://solverfox.dev/writing/no-implicit-children/). Now it needs to be listed explicitly when defining props as mentioned in [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-typescript-definitions) documentation